# How to add items in an array from a collection in firestore in angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add documents from a collection to an array in Angular. The way I am trying to do is getting the documents and then pushing it to array but it somehow does not work. The code snippet for the typescript file is

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

items: Array<FirestoreItem> = [];
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items.push(
      this.firestore
        .collection('test_posts', (ref) => ref.limit(5))
        .valueChanges()
    );
  }
```

The `FirestoreItem` interface is

```
interface FirestoreItem {
  name: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Also the html file is

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="row">
     {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of what you are doing, it would be ideal to make use of pipe and map.  Please find the following:

```
this.firestore.collection<FirestoreItem>('test_posts')
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          take(5),
          map(testPostsDocArray => { 
            return testPostsDocArray.map(testPostDoc => {
              return {
                ...testPostDoc.payload.doc.data()
              }
            })
          }));
      }
```

If you want to fetch all posts based on other criteria, for example, where the userId is equal to 12345, pass in the arguments and remove take(#)

```
this.firestore.collection<FirestoreItem>('test_posts', ref => ref.where('userId', '==', 12345 ))
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(testPostsDocArray => { 
            return testPostsDocArray.map(testPostDoc => {
              return {
                ...testPostDoc.payload.doc.data()
              }
            })
          }));
      }
```